# How to create multiple password checks validation with Yup and RHF?

Tags: yup, react-hook-form

How to create multiple password checks validation with Yup and RHF?
I have register yup schema and i wanna to add multiple password checks validation like in the nike.com

```
export const RegisterSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email('Please enter a valid email address.').required('Email is a required field.'),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .required('required')
    .min(8, 'Minimum of 8 characters')
    .matches(RegExp('(.*[a-z].*)'), '1 lowercase letter')
    .matches(RegExp('(.*[A-Z].*)'), '1 uppercase letter')
    .matches(RegExp('(.*\\d.*)'), '1 number'),
  firstName: yup
    .string()
    .matches(/^([^0-9]*)$/, 'First name should not contains numbers.')
    .max(40, 'First name cannot exceed 40 characters.')
    .required('Please enter a first name.'),
  lastName: yup
    .string()
    .matches(/^([^0-9]*)$/, 'Last name should not contains numbers.')
    .max(40, 'Last name cannot exceed 40 characters.')
    .required('Please enter a last name.'),
  dateOfBirth: yup.string().required('Please enter a date of birth.'),
  country: yup.string().required('Please enter a country.'),
  gender: yup.string().required('Please select a preference.'),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use the `criteriaMode: 'all'` option with `useForm`.

[https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/[![criteriaMode](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/%5B!%5BcriteriaMode) option][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGGpK.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGGpK.png)

Here is a working example (v7):
 https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-errors-validatecriteriamode-all-p9xm6